# How would I generate a series of numbers based on an average?

Tags: average

I'm not too good with math so I'm struggling with this. Say I am given an average yearly temperature and I want to generate twelve random numbers to constitute the average for each month of the year within a certain limit so that I'm not getting temperatures that are unrealistically high. In other words, generating a series of twelve numbers from an already given average, and those twelve numbers equal the average. Does that make sense? I hope it does. Like I said, I'm not too good with math. Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to me.  Where I live, the temperature can be over $100^\circ$ F in the summer and below zero in the winter.  Twelve temperatures near the yearly average to represent monthly temperatures would be ludicrous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose a tight interval of reasonable average temperatures for each month at your location. For example, in Boston for January that might be $(10 ,30)$ in degrees Fahrenheit.

Choose a random value $V$ in each of those $12$ intervals.

Find their average $A$.

Calculate the difference $d = A-B$ between $A$ and the average $B$ you want.

Subtract $d$ from each month's $V$.